# Order of evaluation when using conditional operator

Tags: c#

Is the following behavior expected?

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
}

TestClass instance = null;

// this line throws exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object 
string test1 = "abc" + instance != null ? instance.IntValue.ToString() : "0";

// this works
string test2 = instance != null ? instance.IntValue.ToString() : "0";

// this works
string test3 = "abc" + (instance != null ? instance.IntValue.ToString() : "0");
```

**UPDATE**:

How come this doesn't throw an exception?

```
TestClass instance = null;
string test4 = "abc" + instance;
string test5 = "abc" + true;
```

Comment: Yes, it is expect.

Comment: `"abc" + instance` is never null

Comment: The moment you try to concatenate "abc" and instance, ToString() is called on instance - when this is null you get the exception, so yes, it's expected.

Comment: @CSharpie Still not a very good one. Read the tooltip of the downvote button: "This question does not show any research effort". It doesn't.

Comment: @CSharpie Don´t mix "valid" with "good". The question is of course valid, but it doesn´t show much research-affords.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer: A research would be succesful if you look into operator precedence. For a novice programmer, operator precedence is not obvious and it can be quite difficult to see what's wrong. I remember when I started  programming and judging from that, I find the question legit.

Comment: @HimBromBeere He isolated the behaviour and provided 3 examples. You cant expect everyone to write indepth anaylsis expecially when its obvious that this is a beginners question.

Comment: I don't understand what is your goal: string test = instance?.IntValue.ToString(); Is better approach than setting it to 0 when is null. How you will make a difference when IntValue is 0 and when the instance is null ?

Comment: @fubo I didn't *remove* them, I *moved* them. Comments usually come before the operation, not after. **edit** Oh, now I see what you meant, yeah I f*ed that up, sorry.

Comment: @CSharpie This was more a guess as what the down-vote-button indicates. I didn´t downvote.

Comment: @CSharpie - It doesn't show research effort, its unclear why the output is confusing for the op, and up until the title was changed - it wasn't ever going to be useful (this is still questionable)

Comment: @Darren That is incorrect.  When you use the `+` operator on a `null` and a `string` it will call `string.Concat` which will treat the `null` like a blank `string`.  The issue is that the addition occurs before the conditional and it will end up calling `instance.IntValue.ToString()`.

Comment: @CSharpie - I totally agree with you. It seems bizarre that questions like this get downvoted. As for research efforts, please, come off it. This guy has a valid Q, provided code and obviously didn't know where to go from there - this question is part of their research effort. People are so easy to forget they had to start somewhere too.

Comment: @juharr- Sorry, yes, you are correct, my bad :)

Comment: I've just updated the question, how come test4 and test5 works?

Comment: @HABJAN - Sefe has given you the correct reason/answer.

Comment: @HABJAN That's a completely different question.  It deals with how C# handles addition when one value is a `string` and the other is not, which is basically to check if the other value is `null` and if so it concatenates an empty string, otherwise it will call `ToString` on the other value and concatenate that.

Comment: FYI you could shorten that in C# 6 to `string test1 = "abc" + (instance?.IntValue.ToString() ?? "0");`.  Note you still have to deal with the addition having preference over the `??`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is operator precedence. `+` ranks higher than `!=` *and* `?:`. Your line that is not working could be also written like this:

```
string test1 = ("abc" + instance) != null ? instance.IntValue.ToString() : "0";
```

The expression `"abc" + instance` is *never* `null`, even if `instance` is `null`. That means your expression always evaluates to `true`, which makes you run into a `NullReferenceException` in the `instance.IntValue.ToString()` expression in the case `instance` is `null`.

You can override operator precedence with parenthisation. That means you would have to make sure `instance != null ? instance.IntValue.ToString()` is evaluated first, by enclosing it in parentheses:

```
string test1 = "abc" + (instance != null ? instance.IntValue.ToString() : "0");
```

**UPDATE:**

As far as your questions in the update is concerned: These expressions don't throw an error, because there are two specifics about the `+` operator implementation on a string:

1. It's tolerant to `null` values as long as you have a valid string on the other side.
2. Since the `ToString` method is implemented in `System.Object`, *any value* can be turned into a string with `ToString`. Therefore it is possible to add non-string values to a string (only *on the right side*).

Comment: I understand this grouping issue, I'm just surprised there's no compiler warning, like "Warning, expression can never be null", or words to that effect.

Comment: The compiler could probably warn you about this specific case, but it can't warn you in general, since the `+` can be overloaded and as such the compiler does not always know that the expression evaluates to `null`.

Comment: @Joe Resharper catches it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is. This is because the `"abc" + instance` is evaluated first. Then it checks if it is null (which obviously can't be true). Then in the `true` path, it tries to get the value of `instance`, which is null and thus gives this exception.

The order of evaluation is determined inside the language, which specifies that [`+` is being handled before `!=`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx).